# Where do I find remotes url in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Im new to VS Code, using Webstorm usually. In Webstorm you can type in "remotes" in the action command palette to find the remote url of your git repository. Is there something similar in VS Code to find that url?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12):

1. Open the terminal and run `git remote -v`.
2. Click `Source Control` on the left panel, and then click `...`, select `Pull from` or `Push to`, and you will see the remotes and the urls on top center.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), then:

1. Click on GitLens icon on activity bar on the left
2. Click *Repositories*
3. Expand the *Remotes* menu

---

If the activity bar is not visible, you can hit Ctrl+Shift+P and look for the command **View: Toggle Activity Bar visibility**.

Comment: Thanks , do you know how i can edit the remote url from there?

Comment: You will have to resort to the terminal for that (`git remote set-url`) but that's a different question, since you asked about finding it and not changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a script and I used:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

This gives you the git clone link.